# Matlab plotting multiple time series with different start and ending time stamps on same graph

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series

I want to plot 20 different time series with different starting and ending timestamps. My code is:

```
tempvar = linspecer(12,'qualitative'); %get C for up to 12 different  colors.
startidx = [0 9 20 64 115 160]
endidx =[9 20 64 115 160 250]
%Y is a 20X250 matrix each row is a time seris and each column is timestamp value
hold on
for j=1:size(startidx,2)
       for k=1:size(Y,1)
            coloridx = mod(j,N);
            plot(Y(k,startidx(1,j):endidx(1,j)),'color',tempvar(coloridx,:))
       end
       if j==1
          xlim([0,size(Y,2)]);
       end      
end
hold off
```

However, it is only plotting timeseries for first two time stamps.

Comment: Please edit your question in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: Use `hold on` to plot multiple curves. Also, use `axis(limits)` to set the axis of your choice.

Comment: I tried using hold and set axis limit still it is showing me the same error. I edited and modified the code above